# Plain Javascript to JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My question is the following code is in javascript format can we change this to JQuery format..?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastDiv = "";
function showDiv(divName) {
    if (lastDiv) {
        document.getElementById(lastDiv).className = "hiddenDiv";
    } 
    if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) {
        document.getElementById(divName).className = "visibleDiv";
        lastDiv = divName;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you at least try to translate it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the online handler, and do this:

```
var lastDiv;

$('form > select').change(function() {
    if (lastDiv) {
        lastDiv.attr('class','hiddenDiv');
    } 
    var div = $('#' + $(this).val());
    if (div.length) {
        lastDiv = div.attr('class','visibleDiv');
    }
});
```

Or if the class is only being used for hiding and showing, you can do this:

```
var lastDiv;

$('form > select').change(function() {
    if (lastDiv) {
        lastDiv.hide();
    } 
    var div = $('#' + $(this).val());
    if (div.length) {
        lastDiv = div.show();
    }
});
```